# ERRORS while writing in excel - Java poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've excel sheet of only two columns. The user add y himself and the third one is for checking if the other two columns are valid to insert in he database or not.
While I'm trying to write in the third column after checking the processing going good for couple of rows but if there are more rows, the results for the third column for each row is not correct...

I think the problem here in the for loop if anyone can help it would be really appreciated. Thanks.

here's my code:- ...

```
    @CheckMethodAuthority("PFV2300&limt_print")
    public static void importExcel(Upload upload_data) throws IOException, 
    NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, 
    IllegalAccessException, 

ParseException {    

    String fileName = upload_data.getFileName();
    logger.info("H1:" + fileName);

    final int expectedSheetIndex = 0;  // 
   Sheet sheet = ExcelUtil.openWorkSheet(new ByteArrayInputStream(upload_data.asBytes()), fileName, expectedSheetIndex);

    SYS4000 account = (SYS4000)renderArgs.get("account");

    StringBuffer fileUploadErrorMsg = new StringBuffer();

    final int expectedTitleRowNum = 1;  // 
    List<POS20083> pos20083List = readAllCellsOfSheet(sheet, expectedTitleRowNum, account.user_no, fileUploadErrorMsg);

    int addItem =0;
    int upItem =0;
    int failItem =0;

    File filePath = new File("D:\\play framework workspace\\Coupon_Platform\\public\\sample\\excel\\PFV2300-sample.xlsx");
    InputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    XSSFWorkbook WB = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

    sheet = WB.getSheetAt(0);

    for (POS20083 POS20083: pos20083List)
    {

        for (int i=0; i<=pos20083List.size(); i++)
        { 
           Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
           Cell cell_store_no=  (sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0));
           Cell cell_control_qty =  (sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1));
           Cell cell_error_msg = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2);
           sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);

           for (int j=0; j<=sheet.getFirstRowNum(); j++)
              {
                  if (row == null) 
                  {
                      row = sheet.createRow(i);
                      continue;
                  }
                  if (cell_error_msg == null) 
                  {
                      cell_error_msg = sheet.getRow(i).createCell(2);
                      continue;
                  }
                  if (row.getRowNum()==0)
                  {
                      continue;
                  }

                  POS20083 pos20083 = POS20083.find("merchant_no= ? and store_no= ?",POS20083.merchant_no, POS20083.store_no).first();

                 String sql =  insert into pos20083 (pos20081_id, merchant_no, store_no, control_qty, id)select 60, ?1, ?2, ?3,  pos20083_seq.nextval from dual;


                 String sql2 = " Select count(store_no) from twc_store"
                             + " Where exists (select store_no"
                             + " from pos20083"
                             + " where twc_store.store_no = ?4)";

                 String sql3 = " Select count(store_no) from pos20083"
                         + " Where exists (select store_no"
                         + " from twc_store"
                         + " where pos20083.store_no = ?5)";

                           EntityManager entityManager = JPA.em();
                           EntityTransaction transaction = JPA.em().getTransaction();
                           Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
                           Query query2 = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql2);
                           Query query3 = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql3);

                           query2.setParameter(4, POS20083.store_no);
                           query3.setParameter(5, POS20083.store_no);

                          if (!transaction.isActive())
                          {
                              transaction.begin();
                          }
                          int insertCount2 = query2.executeUpdate();
                          int insertCount3 = query3.executeUpdate();

                          int storeCounts = ObjectUtil.getInteger(query2.getSingleResult());
                          int storeCounts_pos20083 = ObjectUtil.getInteger(query3.getSingleResult()); 

                            if (storeCounts == 0 && ObjectUtil.getInteger(cell_control_qty.getNumericCellValue()) >0) 
                             {

                              cell_error_msg.setCellValue("Store Number ID doesn't exists in [twc_store]");

                              sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);
                             }  
                            if (storeCounts == 0 && ObjectUtil.getInteger(cell_control_qty.getNumericCellValue()) <=0) 
                            {

                             cell_error_msg.setCellValue("Store Number ID doesn't exists in [twc_store] and and control Quantity coudn't be less or equal ZERO");

                             sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);
                            }

                             if (storeCounts == 1 && storeCounts_pos20083 ==0 && ObjectUtil.getInteger(cell_control_qty.getNumericCellValue()) > 0) 
                             {
                              query.setParameter(1, POS20083.merchant_no); 
                              query.setParameter(2, POS20083.store_no); 
                              query.setParameter(3, POS20083.control_qty);

                              int insertCount = query.executeUpdate();



                              addItem++;
                              cell_error_msg.setCellValue(" ");
                              sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);

                             }

                             if (transaction.isActive()) 
                             {
                                 transaction.commit();
                             }

                          file.close();

           if (storeCounts == 1 && storeCounts_pos20083 ==0 && ObjectUtil.getInteger(cell_control_qty.getNumericCellValue()) <=0) 
         {
              cell_error_msg.setCellValue("control Quantity coudnot be less or equal ZERO");
              sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);

            //failItem++;
            //file.close();
         }
           if (storeCounts == 1 && storeCounts_pos20083 ==1 && ObjectUtil.getInteger(cell_control_qty.getNumericCellValue()) <=0) 
           {
                cell_error_msg.setCellValue("Store Number ID already exists and control Quantity coudn't be less or equal ZERO");
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);
                          }

           if (storeCounts == 1 && storeCounts_pos20083 ==1 && ObjectUtil.getInteger(cell_control_qty.getNumericCellValue()) > 0) 
         { 
              cell_error_msg.setCellValue("Store Number ID already exists");
              sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);

         }

       }

    }  
       failItem++; 
  }
           file.close();
           FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
           WB.write(fileout);
           fileout.flush();
           fileout.close();
```

Comment: What does `pos20083List.size()` return?

Comment: pos20083List.size() return the real number of rows in the excel sheet which the user has been already added

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what's going on here, but what's the purpose of `for (int j=0; j<=sheet.getFirstRowNum(); j++)`? It seems like this would iterate over each row (i) in the enclosing loop for as many times as the number of empty rows in the beginning. Is this the desired result?

Comment: this is just to ignore the first row which is the label for each column

Comment: I think `for (int j=0; j<=sheet.getFirstRowNum(); j++)` may be the problem. I don't really feel like installing ExcelUtils to test out the program, but I think if you replace that with `if ( i <= sheet.getFirstRowNum() ) continue;` it might work.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work  even if i delete this for loop too ... the problem is the code working good and the conditions too if i have only one record but if more than one record it doesn't work probably ... what i need is just loop in the cells in column 1 and 2 if match with the conditions so it goes to the insert  query if it doesn't match with the conditions i need to write an error message in front of every row in the cell number 3 in column number 3 ... thats all

Comment: In that case, maybe it is the list size. In my first comment, what I meant was what is the actual integer returned by `pos20083List.size()` when you run it on a sheet with more than 2 rows. Are you sure that the List actually contains all of the rows? I can't find any reference for `readAllCellsOfSheet()`, is this a custom function you've written?

Comment: List<POS20083> pos20083List = readAllCellsOfSheet(sheet, expectedTitleRowNum, account.user_no, fileUploadErrorMsg);
its above the for loop ...    also pos20083List it contains only the actual number of the rows in the excel sheet ...

Comment: Basically what I'm saying is I think `pos20083List` might only have one item in it. If it only has one item in it, it's only going to check one row because `pos20083List.size()` will return 1.

Comment: pos20083List it return only the number of rows in the excel sheet but when the loop finish i can see heaps of loops much more than the pos20083List.size ?? and also for that reason if more than one row in the excel sheet the cell values overwritten and becomes wrong in the cell index of position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've found out the bug and i fixed it**

there are was three loops

1-   for (POS20083 POS20083: pos20083List)
2-   for (int i=0; i<=pos20083List.size(); i++)
3-   for (int j=0; j<=sheet.getFirstRowNum(); j++)

so if we remove the first one which isn't useful here because we are getting the data always from the excel sheet so it will works good ...

also the same for the third one too as well its not very useful here in my task too as well ...

so what i need is only the this loop

for (int i=0; i<=pos20083List.size(); i++)

and we can replace the pos20083list which was return the real number of row with this line

int rows = sheet.getPhisicalNumberofRows() - 1

Thanks so much **Layne Bernardo** for your efforts